# Styling for React Navigation header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I would like to style the React Navigation header with something custom. As per the screenshot below, I have already did most of the styling to customise it accordingly, however one element which is left though is the back arrow key as you can see it is still rendering in its default colour.

[image: VintHub header iOS]

Answer (score 0):

To change color of the arrow, set `headerTintColor`

```
static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Title',
    headerTintColor: 'red',
  };
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work in the first place, I had that command included in the code and that did happen to change the colour of 'VintHub' as desired but left out the arrow for some odd reason.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of react-navigation are you using? The docs say that in some earlier versions this syntax will work:

```
header: { tintColor: '' }}
```

Comment: I am using the latest version of React Navigation which is 
"react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.21". Yes I did notice in docs, that older versions of react navigation, require the syntax as you provided.